# Are $\mathbb{F}_{p^{d-1}} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ Galois Extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I know that $\mathbb{F}_{p}\subset \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is Galois extensions and the degree of extension $[\mathbb{F}_{p^d} : \mathbb{F}_{p}]=d$.

but my question is :-

1. $\mathbb{F}_{p^{d-1}} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is Galois Extensions
2. $\mathbb{F}_{p^k} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is Galois Extensions

in both case $p$ is prime and $d,k$ are integers ( also $ k>d$).

Comment: Are you asking if they are subsets?

Comment: @SirJective Sorry if I do not give detail. but I means. Are the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ and are the extension is Galois?

Comment: I'm afraid it looks like you have misunderstood a few things. Asking question 1 is partly asking that can a set of $p^{d-1}$ elements be a subset of $p$ elements. It feels more likely that you wanted $\Bbb{F}_{p^d}$ on the right. Question 2 has been asked so many times on our site that I have lost count. Gimme a minute to find a good duplicate original.

Comment: Hmm. No good ones yet. Apparently those don't get highly voted (no surprise).

Comment: In first one there was a typo i just corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbf F_{p^k}\subset\mathbf F_{p^d}$ if and only if $k\mid d$.

And, yes, in that case, the extension is Galois. This is because the Galois group $\;\operatorname{Gal}_{\mathbf F_{p^d}/\mathbf F_p}$ is abelian, isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/d\mathbf Z$, hence all its subgroups are normal.